# SQL Query for difference between current and previous row by GROUP

Tags: sql, group-by, subtraction

I am fairly new to SQL. I have the following table structure. For a given SITEID and a given YEAR, I am trying to find the "new" CLASS that was added i.e a CLASS that was not present in the previous year. Each site can have multiple classes.

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>SITEID</th><th>YEAR</th><th>CLASS</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2007</td><td>A</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2007</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2008</td><td>A</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2008</td><td>B</td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2008</td><td>C</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

In the above case, the final output that I am looking for is:

```html
<table><tbody><tr><th>SITEID</th><th>YEAR</th><th>CLASS</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2007</td><td> </td></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>2008</td><td>C</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Would really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: What if more than one class was added on a given year, do you want two rows in the resultset for that year? Also, why don't classes A and B show up in the resultset in 2007, since they do not appear in earlier years (there are no earlier yers).

Comment: Which database are you using: mysql, oracle, sql-server...?

Comment: Hi GMB, Thanks for responding. More than one class can be added in a given year. In such a case, I would want all the new CLASSES to be displayed. I am using SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this (please replace temp table with your table):

If you are using SQL server, then you can use Common Table Expressions (CTE) as blow:

```
 IF (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp_table') IS NOT NULL)
    BEGIN
      DROP TABLE #temp_table
    END;

CREATE TABLE #temp_table (SiteId INT NOT NULL, [year] INT, [class] [Char] NOT NULL)

INSERT INTO #temp_table (SiteId, [year], [class])
       values 
(1, 2007,   'A'),
(1, 2007,   'B'),
(1, 2008,   'A'),
(1, 2008,   'B'),
(1, 2008,   'C')


;with temp_cte as
  (SELECT  siteid, [year], [year]-1 as [yearbefore]
            ,STUFF((SELECT '|' + CAST([class] AS VARCHAR(MAX)) [text()]
            FROM #temp_table 
            WHERE SiteId = t.SiteId and [year] = t.[year]
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE)
            .value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),1,2,' ') [class_list]
            FROM #temp_table t
            GROUP BY SiteId, [year]
)
select c.SiteId
       , c.[year]
       , case when t.yearbefore = null then null else right(REPLACE(c.class_list, t.class_list, ''), LEN(REPLACE(c.class_list, t.class_list, ''))-1) end as [class_added]
       , case when t.yearbefore = null then null else stuff(REPLACE(c.class_list, t.class_list, ''), 1, charindex('|', REPLACE(c.class_list, t.class_list, '')), '') end as [class_added_using_stuff]
 from temp_cte c
left join temp_cte t on c.[yearbefore] = t.[year]
```

If you are not using SQL Server (the below works in SQL server as well), then you can use joins (probably need to adjust the queries respective to RDBMS that is in use) as below:

```
select distinct t1.SiteId, t1.[year]
    , case when t1.[year] = m.[year] then null else t1.[class] end as class_added
    from #temp_table t1
    left join #temp_table t2 on t1.SiteId = t2.SiteId and t1.class = t2.class and t1.[year] -1 = t2.[year]
    left join (select top 1 * from #temp_table order by [year] ) m on t1.[year] = m.[year]
where t2.SiteId is null
```

**UPDATE for MYSQL:**

```
CREATE TABLE test_table(
    SiteId INT NOT NULL,
    year INT,
    class CHAR(1)
);

INSERT INTO 
    test_table(SiteId, year, class)
VALUES
    (1, 2007,   'A'),
    (1, 2007,   'B'),
    (1, 2008,   'A'),
    (1, 2008,   'B'),
    (1, 2008,   'C');
select distinct t1.SiteId, t1.year
    , case when t1.year = m.year then null else t1.class end as class_added
    from test_table t1
    left join test_table t2 on t1.SiteId = t2.SiteId and t1.class = t2.class and t1.year -1 = t2.year
    left join (select * from test_table order by year limit 1) m on t1.year = m.year
where t2.SiteId is null;
```

MY SQL Fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c570d57/1) (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c570d57/1/0)

Comment: Hi Sam, Thanks for responding. I am using MySql so I tried the second query. It throws the following error -"Error: near "1": syntax error".

Comment: @M1001 Updated my post for MYSQL

Comment: Hi Sam, this updated MySQL code works perfectly. Thanks a lot for this !

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT SITEID, YEAR, max(CLASS) AS CLASS FROM [dbo].[TestTable] GROUP BY YEAR,SITEID
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Minakshi, Thank you for responding. This doesn't seem to work. I think my original question was a little ambiguous. Multiple new CLASSES can be added in a given YEAR. Consequently, the max() function won't work I think.

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*, lag(year) over (partition by siteid, class order by year) as prev_year
      from t
     ) t
where prev_year is null or prev_year <> year - 1
```

This will return "A" and "B" for 2007.  That is what your question appears to be asking for although it is not the results you provide.

Comment: Hi Gordon, thank you for responding to my query. Really appreciate the help. Your code works well. The one minor issue is that in the example provided, the code returns A and B for 2007. Since there is no year prior to 2007 in my dataset, and since I am using the previous year for comparison, the CLASS column for 2007 should have NA's. I could just run your code as is, and subsequently replace all the values in CLASS for YEAR as  2007 with NA's.